# catch an error on spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, log4j

I use a code like this to execute some transformation and to continue the process even if I have bad value:

```
import scala.util.Try

val data = Array(Seq(1, 2), Seq(3, 4, 5))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
val rdd_test = rdd.flatMap(x => Try(x(2)).toOption)
rdd_test.collect.foreach(println)
```

this simple code return 5 because in my first line, I don't have any value at third position. My question is how to catch the first line in order to use log4j to log an alert message. I want to say something like: `Index Error.` 
Do you have any idea?

Comment: Use map if you want to traverse over Seq, ```rdd.map { x => x(2) }.collect```

Comment: This fails as you are expecting because the first Seq has only 2 elements

Comment: thank you to comment but this is just an example code. my real code treat a very large data and this is a spark streaming job so I c'ant perform a collect.

Comment: collect is for example purposes to show the behavior, the main idea was to use map instead of flatMap.

Comment: any action that comes afterwards will error after the map if seq does not have 3 elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could evaluate it with `Success` and `Failure` and create the `Option` that way:

```
rdd.flatMap{x =>
  val resTry = Try(x(2))
  resTry match {
    case Success(res)  => Some(res)
    case Failure(e) => logger.error("Error: " + Throwables.getStackTraceAsString(e))
      None
    }
}
```